# Looking for guidance on editing an answer to note that it's a bad idea

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I just came across [this Python suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606504/1941213), which, as noted in the comments, is a terrible idea, bound to lead to subtle bugs.

I am inclined to edit the question to point this out more prominently than the comments do, but I'm not sure what the etiquette is. Obviously, the original author will not appreciate it. Do I contact them to invite them to remove it first? How does this work?

Comment: If the post author do not want to edit that point of view in their answer, you are free to vote according to how you see it. You can write an additional answer with sustaining what you want. But putting words in someone's mouth is not OK.

Comment: Apart from "you should not" (in line with @yivi), why do you want to? What is it you want to achieve? The at first glance impressive votes on the anwer are actually very much overshadowed by others. The questioning comments are already very prominently on top and highly upvoted. So, who would benefit? How?

Comment: "What is it you want to achieve?": Reduce the likelihood that anyone will take this advice.

Comment: [lerl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPp3M.png)

Comment: @Will: Probably means new on meta. I was on SO from the start.

Answer (score 12):

> I am inclined to edit the question to point this out more prominently
>   than the comments do, but I'm not sure what the etiquette is.

That seems beyond the scope of community editing. If you want to point out that an answer is bad advice, you can:

- comment to that effect (already happened in your example)
- downvote the answer
- post your own, better answer and have it eclipse the other one in votes

But editing an answer or question to put a warning in front of it is not what editing is for. You're supposed to strictly make posts better with your edits, fix small errors like spelling and grammar, correct outdated links et al. Editing is not to completly change the meaning of a post to suit yours. This is only in scope with community wiki posts.

Comment: I disagree partially on that: comments are temporary notes made to indicate that the post requires an update. Comments can be also easily washed away to a remote discussion. So if you're expert on the matter, it's acceptable to update the post to stipulate in which conditions the answer is applicable or not applicable, or giving details on the consequences of using such a solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful perspective.